# publish events from delegatecommand prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have an event subscription

```
 this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<BusyEvent>().Subscribe(this.HandleBusyEvent, ThreadOption.UIThread, false);
```

However When i try to publish the event from a delegatecommand action the event does not get fired. Is there any known limitation preventing this action.

```
this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<BusyEvent>().Publish(false);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the event is not being raised? Perhaps your subscriber just doesn't handle it because the subscription gets garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation on firing an event from a delegate command. I regularly do this, the user invokes a command from the UI and the associated command action in the view model publishes an event using the prism eventAggregator.